# Saving user Input from Input Command simplepyGUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I am having trouble save the user's name into a list once order is pressed. I also need to store the user's selction with the buttons into the same list--i believe i need a dis tionary for this but I am completely lost.

For example:
John presses Burger, Onions, Bacon, and Eggs. he hits submit.
I need the out put to relay "John's Order: Burger, Onions, Bacon, Eggs. Total: $XX.XX"

is this possible? And maybe if someone knows how to save the output into a onedrive file

here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

menu_dictionary = {
    "Cheese":0.50,
    "Sandwhich":1.75,
    "Pickles":0.25,
    "Hot Dog":1.25,
    "Burger": 3.5,
    "Onions": 0.75,
    "Bacon": 1.25,
    "Eggs": 1.00,
    "Gatorade": 1.25
}
total=0
name= []
sg.theme('Dark Amber')

layout = [
        [sg.Text("Welcome to the MAF Menu")],
        [sg.Text("Enter your name:"), sg.Input(), sg.Button("Order")],
        [sg.Text("Entrees"), sg.Button("Burger"), sg.Button("Sandwhich"), sg.Button("Hot Dog"), sg.Button("Eggs")],
        [sg.Text("Sides"),sg.Button("Onions"), sg.Button("Pickles"), sg.Button("Cheese")],
        [sg.Text("Total $" + str(total), key='Total'), sg.Text(name, key='Order')],
        [sg.Button("Exit"), sg.Button("Clear")],]

window = sg.Window('MAF Menu', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "Order":
        name.append()
        window['Order'].update("Order")

    if event in menu_dictionary:
        total = total + menu_dictionary[event]
        window['Total'].update("Total $" + str(total))
    if event == "Clear":
        total=0
        window['Total'].update("Total $0")

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':

        sg.popup_no_titlebar('Are you sure?')
        break










window.close()
```

I keep getting errors that the list is not populating

Comment: You use `name.append()`. What are you appending to name? You have to give the append method an argument that you want to be appended.

Comment: I don't know what to do, necessarily, but I am trying to take the name inputted into the sg.Input and add that to a list that can have multiple names. Then I want to add all of the ordered items to a list and output the name along with the order and total

Comment: I think what you want to do is `name.append(values[0])`. you statement `event, values = window.read()` reads the input responses and stores them in values.

Comment: Where would i put this name.append(values[0])?

Comment: replace the statement `name.append()`

Answer (score 0):

You just simply not need to append the name as your name is single value comming from textbox, and use a list to keep track of all items ordered

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

menu_dictionary = {
    "Cheese":0.50,
    "Sandwhich":1.75,
    "Pickles":0.25,
    "Hot Dog":1.25,
    "Burger": 3.5,
    "Onions": 0.75,
    "Bacon": 1.25,
    "Eggs": 1.00,
    "Gatorade": 1.25
}
total=0
items = []
name = ''
sg.theme('Dark Amber')

layout = [
        [sg.Text("Welcome to the MAF Menu")],
        [sg.Text("Enter your name:"), sg.Input(), sg.Button("Order")],
        [sg.Text("Entrees"), sg.Button("Burger"), sg.Button("Sandwhich"), sg.Button("Hot Dog"), sg.Button("Eggs")],
        [sg.Text("Sides"),sg.Button("Onions"), sg.Button("Pickles"), sg.Button("Cheese")],
        [sg.Text("Total $" + str(total), key='Total'), sg.Text(name, key='Order')],
        [sg.Button("Exit"), sg.Button("Clear")],]

window = sg.Window('MAF Menu', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "Order":
        print(values[0])
        order = ", ".join(items)
        order = "{}'s Order: {}".format(name, order)
        print(order)

    if event in menu_dictionary:
        total = total + menu_dictionary[event]
        if event not in items:
            items.append(event)
        window['Total'].update("Total $" + str(total))
    if event == "Clear":
        total=0
        items = []
        window['Total'].update("Total $0")

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        sg.popup_no_titlebar('Are you sure?')
        break

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a life savior! I have been working on this all day. If you dont mind me asking, how would you add those prints to the window in the sg.Text(name, key ='Order')]. I am very new to this so it is very difficult for me to follow

Comment: Glad to hear accept the answer for other people who come to learn the same problem & also if it solves your problem, you can simply call window['Order'].update(order) i hope it will solve your problem

Comment: This does not print the name in the window as the name variable is never assigned to anything. In fact the window input values are not read until AFTER entering the while loop. I would dispense with the name variable it is not necessary and delete `sg.Text(name, key='Order')` as it never reads the name.